# Accessing __proto__ in constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a database Manager that is meant to work with any database depending on certain runtime arguments. My current setup has a few factories creating classes differently depending on the function's `strategy` argument.  So for instance:

```
module.exports = function ConnectionFactory(proxyStrategy) {
  // proxyStrategy.connection === ProxyConnectionStrategy
  class ProxyConnection extends proxyStrategy.connection {
    constructor(...args){ super(...args) }
  }
  ProxyConnection.prototype.dbManager = strategy.dbManager;
  return ProxyConnection;
}
```

The `strategy.connection` class defines certain behavior during construction, namely, making use of the `dbManager` property.  I'm able to see it with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.__proto__)`, and I'm even able to assign it to a variable (`const dbManager = this.__proto__.dbManager`), but the moment I try to assign it to `this` or call any functions on it I strangely lose access to it.  Here's an example of this insane behavior:

```
class ConnectionTemplate {
  constructor(URI, dbName, username, password) {
    this.URI = URI;
    this.dbName = dbName;
  }    
  open() {}
  close() {}  
}

class ProxyConnectionStrategy extends ConnectionTemplate {
  constructor(URI='mongodb://localhost:27017', dbName='proxyDb-test') {
    super(URI, dbName)
    console.log('Proxy Dunder', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.__proto__))
    const dbManager = this.__proto__.dbManager;
    const dbConnection = dbManager.createConnection(this.URI)
    // this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
}
//console.log -> Proxy Dunder [ 'constructor', 'dbManager' ]
```

---

```
console.log('Proxy Dunder', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.__proto__))
const dbManager = this.__proto__.dbManager;
const dbConnection = dbManager.createConnection(this.URI)
this.dbConnection = dbConnection;

//console.log -> Proxy Dunder [ 'constructor', 'open', 'close' ]
```

Simply adding this one extra line assigning the property to `this` is enough to somehow lose access to the property altogether, as if the compiler is somehow 'completing' the construction differently in these two cases.  Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with es6

Comment: I tagged it with es6 because I'm creating these constructors using `class`, and trying to access these properties inside `constructor(){}` in the class definition.  Wasn't sure if those details were relevant.

Comment: What's the context of those `console.log` blocks?  Does `Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === ProxyConnection.prototype`?  Are those blocks in correct execution order?  Specifically, it would be very unusual for the `console.log` to be affected by a statement three lines down.

Comment: @Neal [`__proto__` was "standardized" in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Comment: @richremer The console.log blocks are inside the constructor definition, and they appear here in the same order I ran them in. `Object.getPrototypeOf...` is false.  I have never seen a console.log three lines down affect this before either, it's very odd behavior!

Comment: A little more info: 
`const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);`
    `console.log(prototype);`
    `const dbManager = prototype.dbManager;`

The prototype has a `dbManager` property.  Add this line: `this.dbConnection = dbManager.createConnection()` right after and now the prototype is `{}`

Comment: @SamBallan: Did you put them before or after the `super` call? It might help to show the full codes you tried. Maybe even include `strategy.connection`. And last but not least, what are you using to execute ES6, is it transpiled, in what environment does it run?

Comment: @Bergi I've edited the original post to include the information you asked for.  I put them after the super call, `strategy.connection` is a reference to `ProxyConnectionStrategy`, I'm running this code in my mocha tests, and I've tried  both running natively on Node 6 and on Node 4.4 using Babel.    

Could this be some V8 quirk?

Comment: This does indeed look like a bug. Can you reduce it to a minimal example? It seems that this happens when a) the constructor does not create properties and b) the prototype is empty except for the constructor. Can you avoid `getOwnPropertyNames` and `__proto__`, and instead check whether `Object.getPrototypeOf(new ProxyConnectionStrategy) === ProxyConnectionStrategy.prototype` (and possibly `ProxyConnectionStrategy.prototype !== ConnectionTemplate.prototype`)?